# How to calculate the integral of $x\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, primitive-roots

How can we calculate this integral $ \int x \frac{\text{d} f}{\text{d} x} \,\text{d}x $ ?

I have tried both integration per partes and change of variables, but it doesn't seem to work. Of course, we don't know the $ f $ function here.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which change of variable ??

Comment: What happened with *Integration Per Parts*?

Comment: By parts, what @BobbyLaspy wrote happened. And my idea on the change of variable was $ x dx = du$ and $ \partial x = \frac{du}{x} $ but I think I can't mix $ \partial x $ and $ dx $, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most you can say is that $$\int_a^xxf'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=xf(x)-af(a)-\int_a^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Without further information about $f,$ nothing can be said of the integral on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

By parts,

$$x\,f(x)-\int f(x)\,dx.$$

That's all you can say.

Comment: Ok so, actually I can't have the complete primitive for this one, right?

Comment: @Jejouze: how can you hope to have a primitive for an arbitrary function ?

Comment: No, I just wondered if there is some mathematical trick to have a primitive $ \propto f$ , so apparently not. Thank you.